# How do I map API?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, swift4

I'm new to swift language and trying to work on the API below..

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7484,-73.9857&oauth_token=NPKYZ3WZ1VYMNAZ2FLX1WLECAWSMUVOQZOIDBN53F3LVZBPQ&v=20180616

I'm trying to parse the data and then serialise, however I'm not able to map the data.

```
struct Venue: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let contact: Location
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let address: String
    let postalCode: String
}

class DataService {

    private init() {}
    static let shared = DataService()

    func getdata() {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7484,-73.9857&oauth_token=NPKYZ3WZ1VYMNAZ2FLX1WLECAWSMUVOQZOIDBN53F3LVZBPQ&v=20180616") else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    guard let venues = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Venue].self, from: data) else { return }
                    print(venues[0].id)


                } catch let jsonError {
                    print(jsonError)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
}
```

I need to work on venues array ( mainly "id", "name", "location" ( "address", "postalCode" ))

I'm trying to use the codable and decodable, how do I get the the results, please help.

Comment: you can use (https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper), I saw your json, but its big, what keys do you need?

Comment: No, stick with `Codable` instead but change your error handling so that you catch any errors, replace the decode line with `let venues = try JSONDecoder().decode([Venue].self, from: data)`. Also, I just had a quick look at the json data and you must start your decoding from the start of the message ("meta" key), you can't start somewhere in the middle.

Comment: "I'm not able to map the data" - what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: thank you guys for replying so fast.. I need the following keys: "id", "name", inside "location" I need "address", "postalCode". thanks again

Comment: @AndresGomez The API to parse the JSON is irrelevant if you are not able to **read** the JSON. And libraries like `SwiftyJSON` and `ObjectMapper` have become obsolete in favor of `Codable`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake.

You ignore the root object (the dictionary containing the `meta` and `response` keys). And the venues are in the dictionary for key `response`,  a sub-dictionary of the root object

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let response : Response
}

struct Response : Decodable {
    let venues : [Venue]
}

struct Venue: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let location : Location
}

struct Location: Decodable { // both struct members must be optional
    let address: String?
    let postalCode: String?
}
```

And – as Joakim already said in the comments – **never ignore Decoding errors**. Decoding errors are very descriptive. They contain the specific error message as well as the CodingPath of the error.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            result.response.venues.forEach{print($0.id)}
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: hey thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for hours. I'll keep your advice in mind, this was helpful.